# How to load a specific dialog and it's resources without loading every dialog in the sample code?

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

[Github link for the sample code I'm using](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/adaptive-dialog/declarative/60.AdaptiveBot)

In the AdaptiveBot.cs file,

It creates a list of all the prompts available and takes user input and runs the specified prompt.

I want to modify it such that it loads only one dialog(There are 7 prompts in the sample folder and it gives a choice to load any one )

How would I go about to load only one dialog, for example just the MultiTurnPromptBot is needed to be loaded and the rest are not needed.

```
private void LoadDialogs()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Loading resources...");

    //For this sample we enumerate all of the .main.dialog files and build a ChoiceInput as our rootidialog.
    this.dialogManager = new DialogManager(CreateChoiceInputForAllMainDialogs());
    this.dialogManager.UseResourceExplorer(this.resourceExplorer);
    this.dialogManager.UseLanguageGeneration();

    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Done loading resources.");
}

private AdaptiveDialog CreateChoiceInputForAllMainDialogs()
{
    var dialogChoices = new List<Choice>();
    var dialogCases = new List<Case>();
    foreach (var resource in this.resourceExplorer.GetResources(".dialog").Where(r => r.Id.EndsWith(".main.dialog")))
    {
        var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(resource.Id));
        dialogChoices.Add(new Choice(name));
        var subDialog = resourceExplorer.LoadType<AdaptiveDialog>(resource);
        dialogCases.Add(new Case($"{name}", new List<Dialog>() { subDialog }));
    }

    var dialog = new AdaptiveDialog()
    {
        AutoEndDialog = false,
        Triggers = new List<OnCondition>() {
            new OnBeginDialog() {
                Actions = new List<Dialog>() {
                    new ChoiceInput() {
                        Prompt = new ActivityTemplate("What declarative sample do you want to run?"),
                        Property = "conversation.dialogChoice",
                        AlwaysPrompt = true,
                        Style = ListStyle.List,
                        Choices = new ChoiceSet(dialogChoices)
                    },
                    new SendActivity("# Running ${conversation.dialogChoice}.main.dialog"),
                    new SwitchCondition(){
                        Condition = "conversation.dialogChoice",
                        Cases = dialogCases
                    },
                    new RepeatDialog()
                }
            }
        }
    };
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: Are you just asking for a way for the bot to only load one declarative dialog into memory while keeping the rest of the bot the same (with the same 7-choice menu), or are you asking for a way to modify the bot so that one of the declarative dialogs is now the root dialog and the menu no longer exists?

Comment: The latter, I need to load one declarative dialogue such that it becomes the root dialog and remove the menu section all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that `LoadDialogs` is instantiating a dialog manager by passing an adaptive dialog into its constructor. So instead of creating the root dialog that starts all the other dialogs, you can just pass in one of those dialogs as the root dialog since they're all adaptive dialogs anyway. You can see that the declarative dialog files are loaded like this:

> ```
> this.resourceExplorer.GetResources(".dialog")
> ```

And then the adaptive dialog instances are created out of them like this:

> ```
> var subDialog = resourceExplorer.LoadType<AdaptiveDialog>(resource);
> ```

So you can do something like this:

```
private void LoadDialogs()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Loading resources...");

    //For this sample we enumerate all of the .main.dialog files and build a ChoiceInput as our rootidialog.
    //this.dialogManager = new DialogManager(CreateChoiceInputForAllMainDialogs());

    this.dialogManager = new DialogManager(this.resourceExplorer.LoadType<AdaptiveDialog>(this.resourceExplorer.GetResource("MultiTurnPrompt.main.dialog")));

    this.dialogManager.UseResourceExplorer(this.resourceExplorer);
    this.dialogManager.UseLanguageGeneration();

    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Done loading resources.");
}
```

TL;DR: Replace this line:

```
this.dialogManager = new DialogManager(CreateChoiceInputForAllMainDialogs());
```

With this line:

```
this.dialogManager = new DialogManager(this.resourceExplorer.LoadType<AdaptiveDialog>(this.resourceExplorer.GetResource("MultiTurnPrompt.main.dialog")));
```